# vim: Change colorscheme for internal shell

Tags: vim, shell, macros

I'm using the [solarized colorscheme](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) for gvim. I'm using 'light' for normal editing. I want to switch to 'dark' when I invoke vim's internal shell (:sh). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one colorscheme at a time. Additionaly the pseudo-shell you get with `:sh` is **very** limited and, among other limitations, is unable to display colors.

Use a real terminal session instead, or CLI Vim.

Comment: Yes - you can have only one color scheme. I was wondering if there's some kind of hook that gets called when the user switches to :sh - or if I could make a macro that does this.

Comment: The pseudo-shell doesn't support colors: you won't get colorized `$ ls` results or a fancy prompt. I'm not aware of an autocmd event that can be used for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Vim doesn't have an internal shell. It spawns a new shell as the foreground task, inside a "dumb" terminal emulation if using gvim.

The best way to get the same effect when using gvim is to spawn a xterm (or similar), by using `:!xterm` or similar. You can map that to a keyboard shortcut to make it quicker.